# Access contents of Visual Studio project template zip archive from Wizard

Tags: visual-studio, templates

I am trying to build a customized multi-project template for Visual Studio, and I have some file assets that do not belong to any of the projects within the multi-project template. I would like to extract these static assets from the template's `.zip` archive into the destination directory of the new project.

I have the template set up to use a wizard in the `.vstemplate` file:

<sub>Example</sub>

```
<WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>TestWizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>TestWizard.Wizard</FullClassName>
</WizardExtension>
```

I can also confirm that the wizard is executing the `RunStarted` method in the `IWizard` interface:

```
public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This works just fine");
}
```

How can I access the `.zip` file that contains all the template assets and extract those assets to the destination directory? I'm not seeing any properties that would give me access to either location in the filesystem.

Comment: Also, I'm using Visual Studio 2013, however the wizard would ideally work in Visual Studio 2010+, so I didn't tag any particular version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

Could not find anything in MSDN doco on [TemplateWizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.aspx) to help me out. I guess what we're trying to achieve is more to do with VS automation rather then the wizard.

Anyway, stepping through the code and looking at what context you get in [IWizard.RunStarted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.templatewizard.iwizard.runstarted.aspx) I found that the first item of `customParams[0]` points at the project template being crated. Nothing in the doco to give you a clue about it. (Option 1)

Another way to get the same path as described above is to get it via the VS solution. Found the code for this option on [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c657a68a-4700-4726-b433-6b85a968c97e/runstarted-method-of-iwizard-interface). (Option 2)

This should give you a way to get to the extra items you have packaged into your project template. Now its up to you to get them into the solution and add them as items or whatever. You have access to the solution via passed in context `(DTE)automationObject.Solution`.

The code below has no error checking this was my POC. Also since you're getting the items across it's on you to replace/expand tokens that may be inside those items. Code was developed and tested using VS2013, can't see why it would not work in the earlier versions.

```cs
public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
{
    // Pick one of the options below, error checking skipped for brevity.
    // Option 1
    var tempaltePath = customParams[0] as string;

    // Option 2
    var templatePath = ((DTE)automationObject.Solution as Solution2).GetProjectTemplate("Sc.Accelerator.zip", "CSharp");

    // Get the source and destination folders, error checking skipped for brevity.
    var packagePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(templatePath as string);

    // Found this by looking at the dictionary, undocumented token.
    var solutionPath = replacementsDictionary["$solutiondirectory$"]; 

    // Alternative, did not work for me, may be it should to be called from IWizard.RunFinished
    // var solutionPath = Path.GetDirectoryName((DTE)automationObject.Solution.FullName);

    // Copy a file from project package into solution folder, error checking skipped for brevity.
    File.Copy(Path.Combine(packagePath, ".gitignore"), Path.Combine(solutionPath, ".gitignore"));

    // ... 
}
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about this question. IIRC I somehow managed to access the zip of the project template, but VisualStudio had it locked preventing read access. In the end it was easier to include the assets as resources within the DLL rather than try to access a few random files within the zip.

Comment: @zzzzBov Yes, had the same problem with the locking. However found that doing a file copy File.Copy rather then using Zip apis worked. Looks like its using shell to read the files, not getting access denied this way. I'm using the code now.